# Logging in with a StackExchange account causes IE8 to go catatonic

Tags: bug, status-norepro, login, stack-exchange-openid, internet-explorer-8

When I first signed up for Drupal Answers, instead of my normal MyOpenID identity I created a StackExchange account -- by "mistake" since I somehow missed the MyOpenID option.

I've since signed back up with DA using MyOpenID, but I thought it might be useful to report that I cannot sign in to Drupal Answers with that StackExchange account when in IE8 because as soon as I click the "Login with StackExchange" button:

[image: Login with StackExchange]

IE8 goes catatonic and within one to three seconds no tab nor control surface in the browser is accessible.  IE8 is locked up tighter than a drum and the only way to get out of it is to go into the Task Manager and force close IE.  It is very reliable -- I can make it happen every time.  This is on WinXP SP3. Everything is fully patched.

This doesn't happen with FireFox.  I haven't tried it with any other browser.

I have Event Log info for this.  It usually produces two events when it hangs.  Here's the one that says it is IE hanging:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   Application Hang
Event Category: (101)
Event ID:   1002
Date:       5/21/2012
Time:       3:25:58 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   OFM11236
Description:
Hanging application iexplore.exe, version 8.0.6001.18702, hang module hungapp, version 0.0.0.0, hang address 0x00000000.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
Data:
0000: 41 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74   Applicat
0008: 69 6f 6e 20 48 61 6e 67   ion Hang
0010: 20 20 69 65 78 70 6c 6f     iexplo
0018: 72 65 2e 65 78 65 20 38   re.exe 8
0020: 2e 30 2e 36 30 30 31 2e   .0.6001.
0028: 31 38 37 30 32 20 69 6e   18702 in
0030: 20 68 75 6e 67 61 70 70    hungapp
0038: 20 30 2e 30 2e 30 2e 30    0.0.0.0
0040: 20 61 74 20 6f 66 66 73    at offs
0048: 65 74 20 30 30 30 30 30   et 00000
0050: 30 30 30                  000
```

Here's the other Event:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   Application Hang
Event Category: None
Event ID:   1001
Date:       5/21/2012
Time:       3:17:55 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   OFM11236
Description:
Fault bucket 1180947459.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
Data:
0000: 42 75 63 6b 65 74 3a 20   Bucket: 
0008: 31 31 38 30 39 34 37 34   11809474
0010: 35 39 0d 0a               59..
```

I hope this is useful information for someone.

Comment: +1 because I had to look up "catatonic".

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume this has been fixed. As a side note, we don't support this version of IE.